Open multiple Bootstrap Toasts instead of overriding the same Instance
I am trying to call multiple instances of a bootstrap toast in Vue3. When I call a new Instance the old one gets overwritten but I want the old one to stay. I saw some libraries with this functionality (example), but there is probably a easy out of the box solution that I am not finding.
Simplified code:
<template>

  <div class="toast" id="toastInfo">
    <div class="toast-header">
    Title
    </div>
  </div>

</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
  import {Toast} from "bootstrap";

  function showToast(){
   new Toast(document.getElementbyId('toastInfo')!,{animation:true}).show();
  }

  onMounted(()=>{
    // open first toast
    showToast();
    // open a second toast but it overrides the 1 one
    showToast();
  });
</script>


I am using Vue3, Bootstrap 5.12, ts with composition api in Intellij

You evidently need to have multiple  elements and output them with v-for if a list is supposed to be dynamic. It's generally a bad idea to use vue and vanilla dom libs because this results in an uncontrollable mess if not done properly. You can stick to using vue-specific wrappers if possible

Never link "link".
